# How to know the column name of the table when clicked on any row in angular

Tags: angular

I am wring the angular code to highlight the row on clicking on a row . But the row should not be highlighted when a particular column (One column out four columns).So I want to check the column name where the click event is generated so that I want to highlight the wow.

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to answer such a vague question without any actual code, but basically like you said - listen for click event on an element, if the element is row and the click is not on the list of banned columns - paint the row.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
  bannedColumns = ['cdk-column-weight', 'cdk-column-symbol'];
  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
  onClick(e: HTMLElement) {
    console.log(e);

    if (e.getAttribute('role') === 'cell') {
      if (e.parentElement?.getAttribute('role') === 'row') {
        if (Array.from(e.classList).some((r) => this.bannedColumns.includes(r)) === false) {
          console.log('row not banned!');
          e.parentElement.style.cssText += 'background-color:yellow';
        } else {
          console.warn('banned column was clicked');
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-amqix9?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts